# I am working on a C# program. I have about four different forms. Exiting out of the forms doesn't stop the process. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

This is how I open a new form

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();

        //Sets the Add New Button to Color WhiteSmoke
        this.button1.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

        //Hides current form (Form 1)
        this.Hide();
        //Displays Form 2
        f2.ShowDialog();

    }
```

This is how I close my forms. What am I doing wrong?

```
 private void Form1_Close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not call `Environment.Exit`.  Instead, just `Close()` your forms.

Comment: What process are you talking about?

Comment: After `f2.ShowDialog()`, your Form 1 stays hidden, hence never closed.

Comment: What about `Application.Exit()`?

Comment: use `this.Dispose()` then.

Comment: Try `F2.Show()` instead of `F2.ShowDialog`. Consider using MDI.

Comment: Must read [this](https://www.mindstick.com/blog/196/application-exit-this-close-and-this-dispose)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Environment.Exit()` to terminate your process. And it certainly doesn't make sense to loop over all your open forms, calling `Exit()` for each; only the first call will succeed, because the entire point of the method is _to stop the process_. You haven't shown any code that would actually _close_ a form; if your code ever did call `Exit()`, the process would be terminated, so that means `Form1_Close()` is never being called, which means `Form1` is never being closed. Provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech I am guessing he means the executable. (MyApplication.exe, view-able in task manager)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `Environment.Exit(0)`, try calling [Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    form.Close();
}
```

[Another option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: This might not be the best option. Closing a form while enumeration the OpenForms collection, might throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Form1's close event is **not** called if the form is hidden. 
So don't hide the Form. In fact - never hide the form :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    //Sets the Add New Button to Color WhiteSmoke
    this.button1.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

    //Hides current form (Form 1)
    this.Hide(); //<-- delete this
    //Displays Form 2
    f2.ShowDialog();
    f2.Dispose(); //<--  necessary when using ShowDialog()

}
```

And delete all of this:

```
private void Form1_Close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

That should make the process close then you close `Form1`

Comment: `f2` should be disposed of with a `using` statement, not an explicit call to `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in the Form1_FormClosing() Method:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            // Make sure form is visible before closing //
            form.Show();
            form.Close();
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, simple solution is that pass your Form1 object reference in Form2 contructor and call Form1.Close in Form2_Closing Event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Window
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);

        this.Hide();

        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

Call Form1 close event when Form2 is closed.

```
public partial class Form2 : Window
{
    Form1 frm;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(Form1 frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.frm = frm;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Close();
    }

}
```